# Why does any $\lfloor x+yi\rfloor\gets\lfloor x\rfloor+\lfloor yi\rfloor$?

Tags: complex-numbers, modular-arithmetic, ceiling-and-floor-functions

---

## Background

---

Now as you might or might not know, I enjoy creating [Minesweeper puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A86115+is%3Aq+%22filling+in+an+8x8+minesweeper+grid+with+mines%22) on Puzzling.SE.

I was recently thinking of introducing a complex mines gimmick (where one complex mine is equivalent to $i$ mines, where $i=\sqrt{-1}$), however I wasn't really sure how well it would fare if I decided combine this gimmick and the modular arithmetic gimmick. (I have done only once due to this being just a really hard gimmick to perform [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122948/filling-in-an-8x8-minesweeper-grid-with-mines-day-5-mod-4?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C132.9141))

As you might know,$$x\pmod n\ge x-n\lfloor x/n\rfloor\quad n\ne0$$However, I wanted to know what would we do in the case of$$(x+yi)\pmod n$$since obviously we could rewrite this as$$x+yi-n\lfloor(x+yi)/n\rfloor\quad n\ne0$$but my question was at this point

> Can we simplify this further?

So, I ran two tests on Wolfram Alpha, and here are the results:

| Input | Ouput |
| --- | --- |
| $\lfloor1+2.5i\rfloor$ | $1+2i$ |
| $\lfloor1.5+2.5i\rfloor$ | $1+2i$ |

So it really just seems that we can rewrite our function for a complex number modulo a real number as$$x+yi-n\lfloor x/n\rfloor-n\lfloor yi/n\rfloor\quad n\ne0$$however I decided to run one more test just to make sure I was right:$$\operatorname{mod}(1.5+2.5i,1)$$which should give us$$x+yi-n\lfloor x/n\rfloor-n\lfloor yi/n\rfloor\quad n\ne0\\\overset{x=1.5,y=2.5,n=1}{\gets}1.5+2.5i-1-2i=0.5+0.5i$$although WA apparently gives us [$-0.5+0.5i$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=mod%5C%2840%291.5%2B2.5i%5C%2844%291%5C%2841%29), although I feel like that might just be an accidental mess up on WA's part.

---

### My question

---

Why does any$$\lfloor x+yi\rfloor\gets\lfloor x\rfloor+\lfloor yi\rfloor$$

---

##### Links to tests that I ran

---

<sup>[[1]](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=floor%5C%2840%291.5%2B2.5i%5C%2841%29)</sup>

<sup>[[2]](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=floor%5C%2840%291%2B2.5i%5C%2841%29)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1/2$ and $-1/2$ are congruent modulo $1$ since their difference is a multiple of $1$. So either answer might be considered correct. The positive answer is the only correct answer if you insist that the result of the "mod $n$" operator be a number in the range $[0,n)$. That's an assumption software often makes, but need not.  Mathematicians don't usually think of mod calculations in operator terms.